# Return Key from SQL (Access) after Insert

Tags: sql, r, ms-access, rodbc

### Background

I am using `RODBC` from R to insert records into Access. I am using the following process to insert a bunch of records into a few related tables.

**1.** Open the connection and start a transaction (or rather set autoCommit to manual).

```
library(RODBC)
library(RODBCext)

con <- odbcConnectAccess2007(my_db_location)
odbcSetAutoCommit(con, autoCommit = FALSE)
```

**2.** Append a bunch of data into `Table1` in Access using a parametric INSERT using `RODBCext`.

Immediately after this grab the last inserted identity value. I have read `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` is better to use than `@@IDENTITY` for T-SQL, but it will not work in Access for me.

```
# ...the code to append...

sql_code <- "SELECT @@IDENTITY AS LastKey;"
sqlQuery(con, sql_code)
```

**3.** End (commit) the transaction.

```
odbcEndTran(con, commit = TRUE)
```

### Question

Say `Table1` has a column `ID` which is the auto-number primary key with 1000 records in it already. If I add 10 more records into `Table1` and the `SELECT @@identity` statement returns 1209, is it safe to assume that I just inserted records 1200-1209? Or is it possible that either that 1209 is not what I just entered (due to other users) and/or the records I inserted were nonsequential?

I am assuming that doing all of this within a single transaction guards me from of these things, but am not the most knowledgeable with SQL. I also really do not have concurrent users for this database, but I still like to be as safe as possible.

Comment: If other users are entering records simultaneously then 1209 might not be the last record you entered. There is no guarantee that IDs are generated sequentially and increasing, however, I have never experienced otherwise and really should not matter.

Comment: *with 1000 records*...did you mean 1200 records? And I am not understanding your question. Why can't you query the table to check what the 1209 signifies? Also, why does it matter the autonumber is not sequentially ordered?

Comment: @Parfait, those were notional numbers. Basically there is no guarantee the next available autonumber is `n + 1` or `(max(id) + 1)`. Point is, its *something*. The autonumber is monotonic increasing, but not necessarily sequential. So basically I might insert 10 records with the 10th being 1209, but it might start at 1150 and skip a few up to 1209.

@June7, yeah that is what I suspected. I am trying to figure out a "safe enough" way to do this.

Comment: "Like to be as safe as possible" - safe from what? If you already understand there could be gaps in sequence and multiple user inputs intermingled, what is the issue here?

Comment: That's fair. Basically edge cases. Consulting leads you to weird and sometimes bad solutions... I am being trapped into a technology solution I'd rather not use. I can tell the users to only have one person inserting at once. It's a small group. So if I just have to issue that unfortunate constraint, it's "safe enough". I know it's somewhat of a weird question.

Comment: The issue is I don't know SQL that well and am not sure if there is something obvious that makes this a bad idea to somebody who knows better. Also that there is a "real" way to do this that I do not know about and this is some duct tape solution. I guess my question was if having it all in a transaction "helped". But I appreciate the comments.

Comment: I still don't understand what it is need to be 'safe' from. So what if multiple users enter records and they are intermingled in ID sequence? A transaction allows work to be reversed without corrupting data integrity (no orphans or otherwise invalid entries) in case a run-time error is encountered. This 'undo' could result in sequence gaps which should be irrelevant.

Comment: So your requirement is to retrieve the autogenerated ids for all the records you inserted, right? For MS Access, the @@IDENTITY approach works. Per the MS documentation, "@@IDENTITY - Contains the last identity value generated in any table in the current session. @@IDENTITY can be affected by triggers and may not return the identity value that you expect." So if you do not use any triggers, and your connection does not drop, selecting @@IDENTITY immediately after inserting 1 record will return the desired id.

Comment: There are perhaps better approaches. For example, if you can define a surrogate key in your data, i.e. 1 or more columns, which combined, are guaranteed to be unique. Then you can query for the id with a select statement using the values in the surrogate key. If your data does not have a surrogate key, then you are allowing for duplicates. What does it mean to you to have 2 rows that are only different by the value of the id? That's a business logic question.

Comment: Yeah, I can have meaningful duplicates. I did not engineer the source data. I have some unfortunate requirements in this task. @BigFinger I think that is what I was looking for. Sounds like `@@IDENTITY` is scoped to the current connection so will give me what I need and what other users are doing being irrelevant. I was struggling to find that nuance in documentation and I don't think that is true with SQL Server. @June7 these were helpful comments to me working through this. Basically you convinced me I want to pull the `@@IDENTITY` after each row, not at the end and subtract backwards.